# NameError: name 'learner' is not defined - from fastai.vision

Tags: python, fast-ai

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-94eb7b0557cb> in <module>
----> 1 from fastai.vision import *
      2 import pickle as pkl
      3 import builtins

~/anaconda3/envs/FGMLCI/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastai/vision/__init__.py in <module>
     10 from .. import vision
     11 
---> 12 __all__ = [*basics.__all__, *learner.__all__, *data.__all__, *image.__all__, *transform.__all__, *tta.__all__, 'models', 'vision']
     13 

NameError: name 'learner' is not defined

--------------------------------------
version :
fastai==1.0.60

torch==1.2.0
torchvision==0.4.0a0+6b959ee
```

Comment: It's an error within the library. I'm not sure what solution you're looking for here. Did you make a github issue or contact the developers?

Comment: when I am importing from fastai.vision import *  ------ NameError: name 'learner' is not defined error is coming up

Comment: I see that. And you're doing nothing wrong, so the installation is broken. Again, have you reported the issue to the developers of FastAI?

Comment: What is your OS? I can't seem to reproduce your problem on Linux and Mac, fastai==1.0.60.

Answer (score -2):

it happened me with fastai version 2, my problem is that I deleted this import by accident

from fastai.vision.all import

just for the ones that have this problem in version 2